# threading module. Not sure if I created multiple threads

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am trying to learn the "threading" module. However, I am not sure I was able to create multiple threads.

```
import threading
import time
def somefunction():
    for loop in range (10):
        print "thread sleeps for 20 seconds"
        time.sleep(20)
        print "thread %d woke up"

counter = 0
while counter < 10:
     threader = threading.Thread(target=somefunction())
     counter = counter +1
```

When I run the following command, it only returns one NLWP.

```
ps axo pid,ppid,rss,vsz,nlwp,cmd | grep -i python
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the reference in the parameter `target` to `somefunction` and not call the function.

```
import threading
import time
def somefunction():
    for loop in range (10):
        print "thread sleeps for 20 seconds"
        time.sleep(20)
        print "thread %d woke up"

for counter in range(10):
     threader = threading.Thread(target=somefunction)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. 
However, I have a question.


In order to close all the threads I can add this at the end of the code?




      threader.join()